# Randomly generation of particles sizes and coordinate within a cube

Tags: python

How can I randomly different coordinates(x,y,z) for at least 200 times provided that the coordinates do not overlap.

I tried to generate the random particles with the following conditions. i.The generated particle must be within the cube
ii. The particles must not overlap and with a minimum distance.
It happens that it kept running infinite loop

Comment: Are you sure you can fit 200 particles within your restrictions?

Comment: The cube size is 50cubic millimeter the particle size range between 2.39 to 12.0mm.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import math

# Define the size of the cube
cube_size = 10

# Define the minimum distance between particles
min_distance = 0.5

# Define the number of particles to generate
num_particles = 200

# Define a function to check if a new particle overlaps with existing particles
def does_overlap(new_particle, particles, min_distance):
    for particle in particles:
        distance = math.sqrt((new_particle[0]-particle[0])**2 +
                             (new_particle[1]-particle[1])**2 +
                             (new_particle[2]-particle[2])**2)
        if distance < min_distance:
            return True
    return False

# Generate the first particle at a random location within the cube
particles = [(random.uniform(0,cube_size), random.uniform(0,cube_size), random.uniform(0,cube_size))]

# Generate subsequent particles, each time checking that their location does not overlap with any previously generated particles
while len(particles) < num_particles:
    new_particle = (random.uniform(0,cube_size), random.uniform(0,cube_size), random.uniform(0,cube_size))
    if not does_overlap(new_particle, particles, min_distance):
        particles.append(new_particle)

# Print the generated particles
for particle in particles:
    print(particle)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).